# how to divide table contents into second page on thujohn pdf using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pdf

I have a large single pdf document which consists of multiple records.I need to break or split the table records into second pages in the pdf using laravel.

Using the below codings in the controller the table records are not fully displayed.Some table records are missing in that pdf file.so I need to show the missing table records into second pafe of the pdf file.

```
    private function generatePdf($customerstatement, $content) {

    if (!is_dir(RECEIPTS_DIR)){
        mkdir(RECEIPTS_DIR, 0755, true);
    }        
    $outputName = $customerstatement->card_id . '-' . strtoupper(date("MY"))   .'.pdf';
    $pdfFileName = RECEIPTS_DIR.'/' . $outputName;
    $view =  View::make("admin.document.statement", compact('customerstatement', 'content'))->render();
    $pdf = new \Thujohn\Pdf\Pdf();
    $bytes_written = File::put($pdfFileName, $pdf->load($view, 'A4', 'portrait')->output());
    if ($bytes_written === false) {
        throw new \Exception("Unable to produce pdf statement");
    }
    $customerstatement->pdffile = $outputName;
    $customerstatement->save();
    return $outputName;  
}
```

The below codings are written in the blade file for showing the records in the pdf.

```
 <tbody> 
  <tr>
       <td colspan="7"><b>{{ $customerstatement->customer->card_id }} - {{ $customerstatement->customer->fullName }} </b>
       </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
       <td colspan="7"><b>Beginning Balance : {{ $customerstatement->beginning_balance }}</b>
       </td>
  </tr>


   @foreach ($customerstatement->statements as $statement)
                <tr>
                    <td width="7em">{{{ $statement->date }}}</td>
                    <td width="15em">{{{ $statement->memo }}}</td>
                    <td width="6em" align="center">{{{ $statement->debit }}}</td>
                    <td width="6em" align="center">{{{ $statement->credit}}}</td>
                    <td width="6em" align="center">{{{ $statement->closing_balance}}}</td>                          
                </tr>
    @endforeach

   </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
       <tr>
       <td colspan="7"><b>
            {{ $customerstatement->customer->card_id }} - {{ $customerstatement->customer->fullName }} </b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="7"><b>Beginning Balance : {{ $customerstatement->beginning_balance }}</b></td></tr>
               <?php $i=0 ?>
                @foreach ($customerstatement->statements as $statement)
                <?php $i++ ?>
               <tr>
                   <td width="7em">{{{ date("d-m-Y", strtotime($statement->date) )}}}</td>
                   <td width="15em">{{{ $statement->memo }}}</td>
                   <td width="6em" align="center">{{{ $statement->debit }}}</td>
                   <td width="6em" align="center">{{{ $statement->credit}}}</td>
                   <td width="6em" align="center">{{{ $statement->closing_balance}}}</td>    
                   <td ><?php
                           if($i==25){ ?>
                           <?php $i=0 ?>
                               <div style="page-break-after: always;"></div>  
                        <?php   }
                    ?></td>
               </tr>
```